# Insert Profile Information in Slide Out Menu UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently working on a project for school.  I'm making an App in xcode written in Objective-C. I've already made a Slide Out Menu which is a UITableView. Now I'd like to have in my UITableView some profile information. The profile information consists of a photo, some statistics and a button.I've searched on the internet but haven't found a solution yet, this can also be due to the fact that I don't know the correct name to search for.

I've inserted an image of an example of what I want to make (inside the red square). [Image of an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8OVo.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put the UI elements in a view then in your view controller's viewDidLoad (or viewDidLayoutSubviews if you're using auto layout) call:

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.profileInfoView];
```